# Hypnosis software using gradual binaural induction and custom text to voice suggestions

Tags: audio, health

There was once a wonderful software app that did this long ago, but the company behind it went out of business, all licenses expired and even bootleg copies won’t work on any modern OS.

I’m looking for self-hypnosis software with the following properties (or as many as possible):

- Uses binaural or similar scientifically supported brainwave entrainment
- Uses appropriate frequencies and gradually entrains to said frequencies
- supports text to voice custom suggestions
- Easy to use

There’s a GNU app I know of but it misses most of the features and is horribly user unfriendly, so I’m looking for something else.

Comment: Welcome to our community Alex!  Can you edit your question to include on which OS you would like the software to run?  Also, please include if you are looking for recommendations for gratis (free of cost) or commercial software.  If the latter, please provide a price range.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend a program that is still freely available but you may need some extra steps to get it running given how OS has changed. (I set up a VM to get it to work with windows 7).

It's called Virtual Hypnotist https://vhypno.sourceforge.net/  and it has a number of aspects you mention. You can play with many aspects of the brainwaves and binaurals, if you have SAP14 installed then it also opens up very easy to use text to speech with many voice settings and customization, intonation. You can select from a range of visuals and sound effects, easy to write script components and alot more.

He has also provided the source code if any of the tech savvy people could help out by building on it and making a modern version that can easily run on windows 11 that would be even better! :)